# Customizing the abntex2 output

Tags: bibliographies, abnt

I am trying to get the right form of this reference:

[image]

The journal's name should be italic, not underlined. I already searched the manual, also I've tried to use the `\citeoption` command, but nothing happened. Does anybody have any idea about it? Anything in my template could be interfering that?

Comment: We don't know what template you're using. Probably the usage of `ulem` to modify emphasis. Otherwise, post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Joseph you got it! I didn't know about \ulem modifying \emph. Thanks for your hint. It is working now.

Comment: Good it worked. I'll adapt my comment to an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove emphasis as underline, remove the `ulem` package, or use it as:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```